# Python syntax error running freshly installed `meld`

Tags: centos, yum, python

I'm installing meld [as described here](http://linuxpitstop.com/install-meld-on-ubuntu-and-mint-linux/):

```
sudo yum install intltool itstool gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 libxml2-utils
```

However, when I try to run `meld` this error appears:

```
File "/usr/bin/meld", line 47
  print _("Meld requires %s or higher.") % modver
        ^
```

And indeed `/usr/bin/meld` has this code:

```
def missing_reqs(mod, ver):
    modver = mod + " " + ".".join(map(str, ver))
    print _("Meld requires %s or higher.") % modver
    sys.exit(1)
```

I'm on CentOS 6.7, Python version 3.3.5.

Could you advise on what I'm doing wrong here?

---

EDIT:

Here's the command line, verbatim:

```
$ meld
  File "/usr/bin/meld", line 47
    print _("Meld requires %s or higher.") % modver
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is a portion of `meld` script:

```
import sys
if "--pychecker" in sys.argv:
    sys.argv.remove("--pychecker")
    import os
    os.environ['PYCHECKER'] = "--no-argsused --no-classattr --stdlib"
        #'--blacklist=gettext,locale,pygtk,gtk,gtk.keysyms,popen2,random,difflib,filecmp,tempfile'
    import pychecker.checker
#
# i18n support
#
sys.path[0:0] = [ "/usr/share/meld"
]
import paths
import gettext
_ = gettext.gettext

gettext.bindtextdomain("meld", paths.locale_dir())
gettext.textdomain("meld")

# Check requirements: Python 2.4, pygtk 2.8
pyver = (2,4)
pygtkver = (2,8,0)

def missing_reqs(mod, ver):
    modver = mod + " " + ".".join(map(str, ver))
    print _("Meld requires %s or higher.") % modver
    sys.exit(1)

if sys.version_info[:2] < pyver:
    missing_reqs("Python", pyver)
```

Comment: @EricRenouf: included the script. Full traceback has the abovementioned lines plus import statements.

Comment: That's python 2 syntax, not python 3

Comment: @EricRenouf: Ouch! I didn't realize Python 3 broke backward compatibility. What now then?

Comment: You might also have python 2 already installed, if so run it with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` is a statement in `python2` just like your script has:

```
print _("Meld requires %s or higher.") % modver
```

But you are interpreting the script using `python3` which does not have `print` statement rather has `print()` function.

You can try to replace all `print` with `print()` with a hope that nothing else breaks, which is not a good solution anyway.

Better just install `python2`:

```
sudo yum install python2
```

and use `python2` as the interpreter.

Comment: Well, I have a bunch of tools installed on my machine that rely on python 3. Wouldn't installation of python 2 affect them because `#!python` would suddenly change from invoking python 3 to python 2?

Comment: @Michael Not really, you can call python2 by its path e.g. `/usr/bin/python2`..it shouldn't remove the current symlink of python to python3..if you are paranoid, you can install in a virtualenv..

Comment: Thanks, that helped.